# (python) rss feed sorting algorithm (complexity)

Tags: python, algorithm, rss, complexity-theory

Today at work I had a very simple task, which was to take an rss feed, which naturally has entry elements, and some of them are similar, but have a later updated date.  The task was to parse the feed into a list of entry elements that are unique, and take the latest entry element of the like entry elements, *emphasized text*based on updated date.  I designed an algorithm that I *think* will be optimal for large rss feeds, and I wanted to check it and get the O notation on it from this group:

so I have a function that does a root.findall('entry') and that produces the list of entry Elements, so...

```
def filter_entries(self,entries):
    d = dict()
    for entry in entries: # STEP 1
        job_link = self.get_job_link(entry) #helper function to extract href of link
        if job_link in d:
            d[job_link].append(entry)
        else:
            d[job_link] = [entry]
     for k,v in d.iteritems(): #STEP 2
         results.append(self.sort_entry_list(v)[0])

def sort_entry_list(self,entry_list): #STEP 3
    return sorted(entry_list,key=lambda entry: parser.parse(entry.find('updated').text), reverse=True)
```

Now: I know that the O of #STEP 1 is O(n) because it's a simple list iteration, then the O of #STEP 2 is also O(m) where m is the size of d, and the O of #STEP 3 is O(s) where s is the size of like entry elements to be sorted by the sorted() function.

so algo = O(m) + O(n) + O(s) <-- right?

so how do I derive the the sum of those max function? Also, is there maybe a better way to do this, when the rss feed is say 500,000 entries?

Thanks in advance for the help

Sam

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why the minus?

Comment: I doubt that the sorting algorighm is faster than O(n*log(n)) :)